# pep8 error on Mininet installation on Ubuntu UTM on Mac

Tags: ubuntu, pep8, mininet

I am getting the following error while installing mininet on my utm ubuntu. I am using ubuntu on mac

```
mininet/util/install.sh 
Detected Linux distribution: Ubuntu 23.10 mantic aarch64
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=11, micro=6, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
Detected Python (python3) version 3
Installing all packages except for -eix (doxypy, ivs, nox-classic)...
your text`Install Mininet-compatible kernel if necessary
Hit:1 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic InRelease
Hit:2 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-updates InRelease
Hit:3 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-backports InRelease
Hit:4 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/mozillateam/ppa/ubuntu mantic InRelease
Hit:5 http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports mantic-security InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
linux-image-6.5.0-17-generic is already the newest version (6.5.0-17.17).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Installing Mininet dependencies
Reading package lists...
Building dependency tree...
Reading state information...
Package pep8 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
E: Package 'pep8' has no installation candidate
```

I have tried different solutions available on net / given by gpt but still i am getting some kind of error. Please help

I have tried different solutions available on net / given by gpt but still i am getting some kind of error. I even installed pipx still nothing was resolved. Please help.